# Performance issue while changing Background of a Relative layout Dynamically

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager, android-gridlayout, background-drawable

I am trying to create a screen where i can select multiple images from SDCard and load them in to **ViewPager** & **Gridlayout** like how in **WhatsApp Sending Multiple images** (like in the below screen shot).

[image: whats app screen shot for referance]

I am able to achieve like in the screen shot by using ViewPager and GridLayout(for below Image selection view). when user swiping the ViewPager I need to change the selector in GridLayout. This Selectoion Change part also Implemented by using Relative Layout as Child of GridLayout and updating the RelativeLayout's Background. Below ade those xmls

**gridlayout_item.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutContainer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/on_select"
android:padding="2dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageone"
    android:layout_width="65dip"
    android:layout_height="65dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/on_select"
    android:padding="1dip"
    android:scaleType="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_multi_seletion.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imagepreviewouterlayout" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/imagepreviewouterlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/imagepreviewlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="5"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="1"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dip" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/on_select"
            android:padding="2dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageone"
                android:layout_width="65dip"
                android:layout_height="65dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/on_select"
                android:padding="1dip"
                android:scaleType="center" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="65dip"
            android:layout_height="65dip"
            android:background="@drawable/extrabtn_style"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/addaccountimg" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/addmoreimageBtn"
                android:layout_width="406dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:clickable="true" >
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/tabbar1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
            android:layout_width="178dip"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/imageselector_btn"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#E9E9E9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendImageBtn"
            android:layout_width="178dip"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/imageselector_btn"
            android:text="Send"
            android:textColor="#E9E9E9" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**on_select.xml (selection drawable)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/box" android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/box" android:state_checked="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/box" android:state_focused="true"></item>
</selector>
```

But i am facing performance issue while changing the Background of relativeLayout on **ViewPager's PageChange(onPageSelected)**. I mean ViewPager page is getting struck for a while and moving.

If i comment that update gridlayout item's background on ViewPager's PageChange(onPageSelected) its moving smooth. below is the code snippet.

```
     @Override
            public void onPageSelected(final int arg0) {

                        if (griditemView!= null)
                            griditemView.setSelected(false);

                        griditemView = imagepreviewgridlayout.getChildAt(arg0);
                        if(griditemView!=null)
                        {
                            griditemView.setSelected(true);
                        }
            }
```

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you [display bitmaps efficientely](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)?

Comment: I am creating Drawables by using Drawable.createFromPath(path); API

Comment: Yeah, if the bitmap is unnecessearily large this would exactly cause the lag

Comment: But i am not creating bit map

Comment: What did you think `Drawable.createFromPath(path)` does? Load the file, decode to bitmap, create drawable from bitmap. What are the dimensions of your images?

Comment: Images from sd card. those may have diff dimentions

Comment: Well there you have it. Just implement [loading bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html), the code is already there. It definitely should speed up

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'll implement that and update